# Generate Trace File in Oracle for Entire DataBase Code

Tags: oracle10g, trace

I have developed an application in C#.net used Oracle 10g for Database.

I have tried to generate trace file using following steps :

1. ALTER SESSION SET SQL_TRACE = TRUE;
2. ALTER SESSION SET tracefile_identifier = ;
3. Execute the query
4. ALTER SESSION SET SQL_TRACE = FALSE;

It works fine and also I have converted trace file generated after executing single query into readable format using TKPROF.

Now I wanted to know how can I generate trace file for whole DB Code used in my application. My application has many quires, writing individual query and repeat above steps manually is difficult task.

Is there any other way to generate trace file for entire Database code?

Answer (score 0):

Look here:
http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14258/d_monitor.htm#CFAIBHEG

Also: ALTER SYSTEM SET SQL_TRACE = true 
http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28320/initparams234.htm

Enabling tracing on database level requires appropriate privileges (ask your DBA).
Be carefull on production, because tracing the whole database will likely slow down the system, and you will get tons of tracefiles, very difficult to analyze.
Using CLIENT_ID_TRACE_ENABLE procedure to tracie only selected calls is a better option.